# AKS cross regional Network policy

Tags: azure, networking, kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

We are planning to build a AKS cluster in HA cross regional using Azure Traffic manager. We intend to apply certain network policies on one region and same needs to be replicated on the other region. 
How can we ensure replication across the multi region ? 
Additionally how can we ensure Storage isolation in AKS region? 
Any leads would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know kubernetes doesnt offer any sync engine. You can use [flux](https://github.com/weaveworks/flux) or any other gitops tool to sync configs between clusters (or rather apply the same config to clusters).